# Constants file with a static Enum and a Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective C (Coming from the world of Java).

I'm trying to create a Constants Header file that can allow Classes to make use of static constants, a static Enum and a static Dictionary.

Here's the Pseudo Code of Constants.h

```
extern NSString* const WelcomeMessage;

typedef enum {
RED,
GREEN,
ORANGE
} Color;

//Use the above Color Enum values as keys to map each color to a message String.

NSDictionary *colorMapper= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    RED, @"Excellent choice. Red is the color of love",
    GREEN, @"Can't go wrong with Green. Green is associated with Nature",
    ORANGE, @"The color is as sweet as a juicy Floridian Orange"
];
```

Constants.m

```
...

- (void)printColor:(Color) color
{
  NSLog(@"%@", [colorMapper objectForKey:color]);

}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to properly declare static constants, a static Enum and a static Dictionary with keys as Color Enum and values of type String. Is this doable (Can a static Enum and a Dictionary with Enums as Keys permitted)? If not are any alternative ways to implement this behavior?

Comment: Everything but the dictionary, which can only be allocated at run time, is doable.  One alternative would be another enum for RED_MESSAGE, GREEN_MESSAGE, etc. but I think you're trying to avoid a big if-else branch in the code.  The only way to get what you want is to relax your constraint that the data is statically defined.  (You can crate an allocated object initialized with static scalar values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[All code typed direct into the answer, expect typos.]*

(Objective-)C has limits on what expressions and types can be used in constant initialisation; these include the primitive types (integers, characters, etc.), strings (both C and `NSString`), but not `NSDictionary` values.

However for Objective-C there is the `+load` method which is called when the binary (application or framework) containing the code is *loaded*. This method runs before any `+initialize` methods. Using this you can achieve what you wish, start with your `Constants.h`:

```
extern NSString * const WelcomeMessage;

typedef enum {
   RED,
   GREEN,
   ORANGE
} Color;

extern NSDictionary * colorMapper;
```

and in your `Constants.m` define a class just to contain the `+load` to initialize your `NSDictionary`:

```
#import "Constants.h"

NSString * const WelcomeMessage = @"...";

NSDictionary * colorMapper;

// pick a hard to type name...
@interface Private_Hidden_Class_To_Init_Dictionary_
@end

@class Private_Hidden_Class_To_Init_Dictionary_

+ (void) load // will execute automatically when this file is loaded
{
   colorMapper = 
      @{ @(RED) : @"Excellent choice. Red is the color of love",
         @(GREEN) : @"Can't go wrong with Green. Green is associated with Nature",
         @(ORANGE) : @"The color is as sweet as a juicy Floridian Orange"
      };
}

@end
```

This code uses the `@{ ... }` Objective-C literal syntax for dictionaries. Note also the use of `@(RED)` etc. as the keys unlike in your code. The keys of an `NSDictionary` must be objects, `@(RED)` is a Objective-C literal which produces the an object of type `NSNumber`.

*(Note: There might be an attribute you can attach to a C function to give it the same run-at-load semantics, however I did not find one listed in the Clang documentation. Using a C function would remove the need for the class.)*

HTH

Comment: Wonderful answer!! Thank you so much!! How can I create an additional method that can accept a selected 'Color' and print it to console? (I've updated the original question with Constants.m that would hold this method)  - (void)printColor:(Color) color
{
  NSLog(@"%@", [colorMapper objectForKey:color]);
 
}

Comment: You need to use `[colorMapper objectForKey:@(color)]`, or better `colorMapper[@(color)]` using modern syntax, as shown in the answer when defining the dictionary - keys *must* be objects and `@(...)` produces an `NSNumber` object from a numeric value. Also I expect you might want to make this a class method (`+ printColor`) or just a function like `NSLog` itself (`void printColor(Color color) { ... }`).

Comment: Thank you! Other than the official Apple Developer documentation on ios, is there another resource you can recommend for  a nice primer on Objective C?

Comment: Everything is in the Apple docs somewhere... and yes it can be a challenge locating it! A maybe less obvious place to look is the Xcode release notes as they document new features in the language as they are released. Other than that there are books/online resources, but sorry I've no specific recommendations